# How would a senior PHP developer design this Login class?

Tags: php, php5

How can I design this class and its implementation so that it looks like it was developed by a seasoned senior level PHP developer that follows all of the best practices? I'm trying to design this class so that it can be reused in other applications. I also have some other questions that are located inside of the code.

Please overlook commenting on the following 2 things:

- Docblock commenting
- Unit testing

### `Login` Class

```
<?php
class Login
{
    private $username;
    private $password;

    //PDO mysql connection object
    private $pdo;

    /**
     * Question 1. 
     * Is this the correct way to use an error object? I am passing it in to 
     * the constructor for DI (Dependency Injection) just like the $pdo 
     * object? I will have multiple classes that need error management. 
     * 
     * Question 2. 
     * Would each class that uses the error object need to have a method 
     * called getErrors() as shown below and should I implement an interface 
     * called 'errors' that has a getErrors() method or should I use an abstract
     * class that implements it once so all classes can use it?
     */
    private $error;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, Error $error, $loginCredentials)
    {

        /**
        * Throw exception if missing Login Credentials 
        */
        if (!isset($loginCredentials['username']) || !isset($loginCredentials['password'])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(
                "Login credentials must be passed into the ". __CLASS__ . " class in the form of an 
                 associative array with the keys 'username' and 'password'."
            ); 
        }

        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->error = $error;
        $this->username = $loginCredentials['username'];
        $this->password = $loginCredentials['password'];

    }

    public function authenticate()
    {
        /**
         * Question 3. 
         * In each class that uses a PDO connection object, 
         * is it proper to do all these database interaction details 
         * in each method that requires database interaction? 
         */
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user = :user AND password = :pass";

        //Prepare statement
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

        //Set fetch mode
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //Set params to bind
        $params = array(
            ':user'=>$this->username,
            ':pass'=>sha1($this->password)
        );

        $stmt->execute($params);

        //If the user is found, log them in.
        if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
            $this->loginUser();
            return true;
        } else {
            /**
             * Is this the best way to set errors?
             */
            $this->error->set('Invalid Username and or Password combination');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Question 4. 
     * Is this the proper way to display errors back to the user? 
     * Once a use submits the login form, the client code calls 
     * authenticate(). If it returns false, it runs this method. 
     */
    public function getErrors() {
        return $this->error->getErrors();
    }

    private function loginUser()
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;
        $this->isLoggedIn = true;
    }
}
```

### `Error` Class

```
class Error 
{
    private $errors = array();

    public function set($msg)
    {
        $this->errors[] = $msg;
    }

    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->format();
    }

    private function format()
    {
        if (count($this->errors) > 0) {
            $errors = '';
            foreach ($this->errors as $error) {
                $errors .= '<p>'.$error.'</p>';
            }
            return $errors;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Implementation

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    /**
     * Question 5.
     * Looking at the below code, is there a better way so that I can comply 
     * with the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle in order to not repeat 
     * the try{} catch() {} block very time I pass a $pdo object into a class? 
     * 
     * Is the proper way accomplished by first creating a new class i.e. PDOConfig 
     * that extends PDO, and inside the constructor put the try catch block? 
     * 
     * If so, is it always better to pass the details into PDOConfig like this:
     * $Login = new Login(new PDOConfig(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS), new Error(), $_POST)
     * or is it better to hard code the constants into the PDOConfig 
     * class's constructor, and then call it like this:
     * $Login = new Login(new PDOConfig(), new Error(), $_POST)
     */
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "There was an error connecting: " . $e-getMessage();
    }

    $Login = new Login($pdo, new Error(), $_POST);
    if ($Login->authenticate()) {
       header("Location: index.php");
       exit();
    } else {
          echo $Login->getErrors();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is everyone doing the password check using SQL instead of PHP? SQL will use a collation when comparing strings that is not always predictable (CI, AI). PHP will compare the strings in a safer way. Just fetch the user by username and check fields (lockout, password, expiry) using PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The numbered questions

#### 1 Correct usage of an Error object?

Probably not. Using DI is fine, creating an object to inject into the construtor where it's not fundamentally required is not.

The use of the term "an Error object" implies it's a common/global concept - I'm not familiar with this. Javascript has error objects for example, PHP has exceptions. In both cases though, they are classes that are created to represent one error and to be thrown and not something that's passed around and especially  not something that's eagerly created incase an error condition occurs.

#### 2 all classes need getErrors?

The Error object is not something I feel should exist.

Ignoring that though, from what you've said in the question, the Error object is supposed to be used with various, possibly quite different classes. Since (I assume) the same instance of the error object is passed around there is no need for the getErrors method at all - just get a reference to the singleton Error instance, and query it directly.

#### 3 PDO usage?

You're better off using some abstraction, doctrine is a reasonable choice if you aren't using anything at all right now.

#### 4 Proper way to display errors?

Probably not. This class isn't presentational, it should be returning only data.

#### 5 DRY try/catch?

Only catch exceptions that you know how to handle. in the example code a PDOException is caught, no corrective action is taken which simply means that a fatal error will be thrown on this line:

```
if ($Login->authenticate()) {
```

since it tries to talk to the database, which isn't connected. You can use [set_exception_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) so that you don't need to scatter try catch blocks around your code where the intended result is to do nothing except logging and show the user (or developer) a 500 error message.

With that said, some more detail in the order points are encountered reading the code:

### Don't mix presentation logic into classes

Unless the class is dedicated to presentation logic - don't put presentation logic in it. This simply means don't return or assume html, instead just return appropriate data (booleans, arrays - as appropriate). The function `Error::format` is an example whereby it would be better to just return the array stack and let something else loop over it and dump to html,json, the log etc.

### Don't create needless classes

The error class doesn't seem to offer any benefits.

I.e. this:

```
$foo = new Login($pdo, new Error(), array(..));
$return = $foo->authenticate();
...
$errors = $foo->getErrors();
```

Could be used almost identically if the error object didn't exist:

```
/**
 * Is this the best way to set errors?
 */
$this->errors['user'] = 'User not found'; // as appropriate
$this->errors['password'] = 'Invalid Password combination'; // or this error
```

If there's a class tracking all errors (why, what's the use/benefit) - it should either be asking individual instances what errors they contain, or some intermediary logic should be doing that. If the error class just contains an array of strings, there's no context to know why of where an error came from. Using DI is fine, but not having a needless dependency is better.

As a related point the function `authenticate` only returns true or null. It would be preferable to always return something:

```
function authenticate() {
    if () {
        ...
        return true;
    }
    return false; // default deny
}
```

### Write reusable/configurable classes

Instead of this:

```
$foo = new Login($pdo, ...);
...
$bar = new Login($pdo, ...); // oops, need to try and login again with different props
```

Make it easy to (re)configure an existing instance:

```
$foo = new Login($pdo);
if ($foo->authenticate($_POST)) {
    ...
}
...
$foo->reset();
$foo->checkOldPasswordTable(); // old passwords were stored with a different hash function
if ($foo->authenticate($_POST)) {
    ...
}
```

### Write testable code

The above point is a pseudo-contrived example, unit tests are possibly a better example of when you'd want to not keep creating new objects.

the login credentials are not something that are required at the time the Login class is created:

```
$foo = new Login($pdo);

$result = $foo->authenticate(array('user' => 'testuser1', 'password' => 'correct password'));
$this->assertTrue($result, "User was not authenticated but expected to be so");

$result = $foo->authenticate(array('user' => 'testuser1', 'password' => 'wrong password'));
$this->assertFalse($result, "User was authenticated with a wrong password");
```

When the time comes to write unit tests, the code shouldn't need to be modified. Changes to make code testable are usually trivial - and just mean planning ahead and having appropriate methods to set and get data.

### Be secure

As indicated by other answers an unsalted sha1 password is weak. Passwords should be stored such that even if someone gets access to the database, they can't determine the original password.

It's *not* hard to store passwords securely, here's some pseudo code:

```
function register($username, $password) {
    $salt = '$2a$10$' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 22);
    $storeThis = crypt($password, $salt);

    return $this->save(array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $storeThis
    ));
}

function login($username, $password) {
    $dbUser = $this->findByUsername($username);

    if (!$dbUser) {
        return false;
    }
    if (crypt($password, $dbUser->password) === $dbUser->password) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

By using [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) and blowfish (the string '$2a$' indicates to use blowfish encryption) passwords are stored securely such that password leaks such as the recent linkedin incident become a none issue.

### Be configurable

In the above code example, blowfish and a cost parameter of 10 is used. Instead it would be better to make the hash algorighm used configurable:

```
protected $_algorighm = 'blowfish';

protected $_cost = 10;

public function setAlgorithm($algo, $cost = null) {
    // verify algo is a possibility and the cost is appropriate
    ...
    $this->_algorithm = $algo;
    $this->_cost = $cost;
}

function register($username, $password) {
    $salt = $this->_getSalt();
    $storeThis = crypt($password, $salt);

    return $this->save(array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $storeThis
    ));
}

protected function _getSalt($salt = '') {
    $length = 0;

    switch ($this->_algorithm) {
        case 'des':
            $template = '%s';
            $length = 2;
            break;
        case 'md5':
            $template = '$1$%s';
            $length = 12;
            break;
        case 'blowfish':
            $template = '$2a$%d$%s';
            break;
        case 'sha256':
            $template = '$5$rounds=%d';
            break;
        case 'sha512':
            $template = '$6$rounds=%d';
            break;
        default:
            $template = '';
    }

    return sprintf($template, $this->_cost, $this>_getRandomString($length));
}

protected function _getRandomString($length = 0) {
    return substr(md5(time()), 0, $length);
}
```

Comment: Hey AD7six! I don't know where to start, your answer was quite descriptive. It is much appreciated. Your answer is definitely going to help a lot of people! Everyone's answer was great but this one goes above and beyond! Thanks for that. In response to what you wrote about the handling errors part. The current project I am working on (like you assumed) has multiple classes. If there is an error when a user logs in, or there is an error when a user submits one of the other many forms, I need some way to display the list of errors to the user.

Comment: I'm very confused on what to do? I also want to learn the best way for much more complex projects than the current one I am working on. I want to learn the best way for complex projects. How would you handle errors? With an array or with an error class? You mention both ways. If I use an error class as a singleton, then I can call the getErrors() method of it. And pass the Error object into each of the classes that use it. But you also mention not using the singleton, and instead using a simple errors array. I'm confused as far as that goes. So I'm kind of just as stuck on the "errors" portion

Comment: as I was when I first made the post. Although I learned a TREMENDOUS amount from everything else you wrote and I really appreciate those teachings!!!

Comment: I [edited the answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/18163/revisions) to clarify that the error object is not something I recommend. if you want to put all errors in a single place you can do so e.g. like this `$_SESSION['errors'][] = "a new error occurred";` and loop on `$_SESSION['errors']` somewhere in your presentational code to advise the user (and delete from the session on display). That would be by querying objects for error or *in addition* to logging errors to an internal class property.

Comment: Thanks!!! So are you suggesting that the best way to capture errors is.. inside of each class that captures errors, whenever an error occurs like "invalid user", "required field missing", etc, would be to do $_SESSION['errors']['Name To Display To Screen']= "description of message to display to user". ? But if I do this, my classes will be sprinkled with $_SESSION['errors'][] = "". Is that still following with best practices? I'm a tough cookie, I know. I just want to do it the best way! :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Red flag

```
     $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user = :user AND password = :pass";
```

Ok, so you've heard that you should hash passwords before storing them, because it turns out that `pass` is a SHA hash. But you don't seem to have heard of salt. The password database is going to be wide open to a rainbow table attack.

I would recommend that you use a framework which has a good password storage mechanism (if there is one). If not, read the **[OWASP Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)** very carefully before you rewrite this code.

Comment: Using a salt is of course something to change, but I feel this answer is misleading. It doesn't mention you'd need another exploit to gain access to the db, to make use of that weakness. I.e. unless someone gains access to the db, it changes nothing in terms of the security of the application. [crypt](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) with blowfish, is a better recommendation than a salted sha1. It's also a single relatively trivial (in terms of effort at least) point, there are other fish to fry. -1 for tone "you don't seem to have heard of salt".

Comment: @AD7six, it's certainly not trivial, in terms of effort or in any other terms. Doing anything security-related correctly is very hard: that's why I recommend using a framework which does it well over implementing it yourself. Various high-profile leaks of password databases over the past year should be sufficient demonstration of the value of storing them properly. Not sure what problem you have with the tone. Too friendly?

Comment: Users don't post their code to be ridiculed for what they don't know.

Comment: @AD7six, ridiculed, no, of course not, but I don't intend or see any ridicule. People do post their code to be *told* what they don't know: that's the point of code review.

Comment: I've noticed that is the tough thing with "text". To one person a word or phrase might sound like a bad tone, and to the person writing the word or phrase, they do not intend for it to happen. But it's ok you guys, thanks for both wanting to help :-)

Comment: Although all answers are great, they still don't answer the question about how a senior developer would design this same class. All password hashing aside! It's great to know about password hashing, but that isn't what I am after with this.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend returning user messages from the Login class, but instead to return a 'status' which can be converted to a message.  This will provide better maintainability and extensibility.  There are a couple of options for doing this. First I'll start by demonstrating a problem with the approach of using an Error object when it comes time to differentiate between different failure scenarios:

```
$Login = new Login($pdo, new Error(), $_POST);
if ($Login->authenticate()) {
   header("Location: index.php");
   exit();
} else {
    // Do something additional based on the failure
    foreach ($Login->getErrors() as $error) {
        if ($error === 'Invalid username or password') {
            // Do something special for invalid credentials
        }
    }
}
```

A better approach to handle this case is to throw an exception when authentication fails:

```
class Login {
    public function authenticate(...) {
        // ...
        if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
            $this->loginUser();
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
}
```

Lets evaluate this from the point of view of code that uses the Login class (consumer code).

```
try {
    $login = new Login(/*...*/);
    $login->authenticate(/*...*/);

    // ... Do whatever needs to happen on successful login
} catch (Exception $e) {

    // Here is where we run into problems with this approach because we
    // don't know for sure why this exception occurred, it could very well
    // be a PDOException
    if ($e->getMessage() === 'Invalid username or password') {
        // ...
    } else {
       // ... Handle other types of exceptions
    }
}
```

This is very fragile and difficult to maintain because every time the message is updated this code needs to be updated as well. You could use a constant for the message, but this still involves a complicated catch clause to determine the nature of the exception and doesn't allow for parameterized messages.  This can be improved by a subclass of exception specifically for login related errors:

```
class LoginException extends Exception {}

class Login {
    public function authenticate(...) {
        // ...
        if ($stmt->rowCount()) {
            $this->loginUser();
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new LoginException('Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
}
```

Now the updated consumer code:

```
try {
    // ... same as above
} catch (LoginException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} /* Other types of exceptions will bubble or can be caught here if it is possible to handle them */
```

This is perfectly fine for a single type of error, but lets suppose the login class is expanded to protect against brute force attacks by locking accounts after a certain number of failed attempts.  The authenticate method would now look something like this:

```
class Login {
    public function authenticate(...) {
        // ...
        $acctInfo = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($acctInfo !== null) {
            if ($acctInfo['locked']) {
                throw new LoginException('Account is locked, you must contact an administrator before you can login');
            }
            $this->loginUser();
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new LoginException('Invalid username or password');
        }
    }
}
```

Now the consumer code:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (LoginException $e) {
    if ($e->getMessage() === 'Invalid username or password') {
        // ...
    } else if ($e->getMessage() === 'Account is locked, you must contact an administrator before you can login') {
        // ... Do something different
    }
}
```

This has the same problem as the first example.  Again this can be simplified by using constants to hold the error messages but the same issues apply.  Another solution would be to create an exception subclass for each type of error resulting in the following consumer code:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (InvalidUsernameOrPasswordLoginException $e) {
    // Common exception handling setup...

    // Differentiated exception handling for invalid credentials...

    // Common exception handling output...

} catch (AccountLockedLoginException $e) {
    // Common exception handling setup...

    // Differentiated exception handling for locked account...

    // Common exception handling output...
}
```

Now we're getting somewhere, there is no reliance on the actual message to distinguish between failure types.  However, this style of multiple catch statements can make it difficult to eliminate duplication.  Lets take a step back and instead of introducing multiple types of exception for login failure use an error code to distinguish failure types:

```
class LoginException extends Exception {
    const INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD = 'login.failure.invalidUsernameOrPassword';
    const ACCOUNT_LOCKED = 'login.failure.accountLocked';

    public function __construct($code) {
        parent::__construct('Authentication failed', $code);
    }
}

class Login {
    public function authenticate(...) {
        // ...
        $acctInfo = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($acctInfo !== null) {
            if ($acctInfo['locked']) {
                throw new LoginException(LoginException::ACCOUNT_LOCKED);
            }
            $this->loginUser();
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new LoginException(LoginException::INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the consumer code will be similar to the code we had before but is relying instead on codes to distinguish between failure types.

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (LoginException $e) {

    // Do common exception handling setup here...

    switch ($e->getCode()) {
        case LoginException::INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD:
        // Differentiated exception handling for invalid credentials
        break;

        case LoginException::ACCOUNT_LOCKED:
        // Differentiated exception handling for a locked account
        break;
    }

    // Do common exception handling output here...
}
```

This is preferable to relying on messages which are prone to change or may not even be the same for each execution.  Consider trying to determine the type of failure for the the following message: `"Invalid password or unrecognized user: $username"`.

Not getting into details, using codes has additional benefits over generating messages in internal classes when your application is localized or when support is added for additional clients.

Comment: Hey pgraham, Thanks for the advice but I'm not sure what you mean when you say this "messages should only be generated at the boundary of your application, immediately before you pass it to the client. Before this the failure should simply be represented as an object encapsulating a status which is not tied to any particular message:" Keep in mind, I am VERY VERY new to programming, and OOP. My first and only language is PHP. I'm trying to learn as fast as I can, but in order to really understand and learn, I need to see simple complete examples.

Comment: If you look at the Implementation section of the code, the status code is only transformed into an actual message (by L10N) immediately before being echoed.  By "boundary" I mean the point where data is passed to user.  In the case of PHP this is usually done with `echo`.

Comment: Oh yeah I saw L10N, I just don't know what L10N is. I have a tremendous amount to learn in order to understand these concepts clearly. I just thought that it would be a good idea to try to find a project that was developed in PHP using the SOLID acronym princples and all of the best practices. Something that is small, and has around 15 classes. Do you happen to know of such a program?

Comment: L10N stands for localization (first letter L, last letter N with 10 letters in between).  In my code sample it is a theoretical class that takes a code and uses that to generate a localized message.  I don't know of any such program off the top of my head but you could start by looking at http://symfony.com/. It's not small but you could probably look at one of its components in isolation.

Comment: I think talking about localization is just distracting - most code doesn't need it. A method to set the texts used in the class however, would be appropriate. Pointing at symfony for someone "VERY VERY new to programming, and OOP" is not a good idea. Symfony's source code is confusing for experienced developers.

Comment: Hey pgraham! I think I am starting to understand what you are talking about with localization. This technique seems really useful! I want to learn it! **So when you say:** "Before this, the failure should simply be represented as an object encapsulating a status which is not tied to any particular message.", are you referring to -- when you wrote, for instance this:  $statusCode = 'authentication.failure.invalidUsernameOrPassword'; 

**If so**, one thing I'm not understanding: your returning a new AuthenticationStatus object that is passed a $statusCode, which seems to be a string?

Comment: but the AuthenticateStatus constructor takes 2 params: $success and $code. What are the $success and $code params supposed to be? And then in the implementation, when you do: L10N::get($authStatus->getCode()), what does the class definition of the L10N class look like? Do I have a different one for each class that has errors? Or is this approach only used for Login classes? I really do want to learn this, it's just complicated to wrap my head around! I kind of have to see the whole picture in order to understand it! Boy I can't wait to get passed this part of my learning curve!

Comment: @AD7six Yes I agree the conversation has veered a bit.  My original intention was to use localization as an example of why the Login class shouldn't be generating it's own error messages but simply error statuses.  I'll have to take your word about Symfony as I am mostly unfamiliar with the internals but was under the impression that it is composed of many smaller projects, one of which might be useful as an example for a beginner.

Comment: @AD7six "...talking about localization is just distracting - most code doesn't need it." I wholehearted disagree, every single project I've worked on professionally has required some level of localization.

"A method to set the texts used in the class however, would be appropriate."  Again, I disagree.  This would create a maintenance problem whenever a new class of error is added requiring updates to every single consumer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class Login {

    private $pdo;
    private $hasher;

    public function __construct(PDO $pdo, IHasher $hasher) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

    public function Authenticate($userName, $password) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user = :user";

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $params = array(
            ':user'=>$this->username
        );

        $stmt->execute($params);

        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            // ... get user row or object say:

            $user = new User(); //or something else

            if ($this->hasher->Compare($password, $user->Password)) {   
                //check other stuff, disabled user, locked etc.

                                /* a PHP session has been already started but we start a new with different session id see session handling on php.net */
                $session = Session::Start($user);

                return $session;
            }
        }

        throw new \Exception('Invalid Username and or Password combination');
    }
}
```

### Error class

If something goes wrong simply throw an exception and handle it. No need for some custom magic error handling stuff.

### PDO usage

Yes you can use PDO like this but if i were you i would create a wrapper for it to minimalize code duplicates and provide more readability. I recommend you to fatch objects from database rows not associative arrays becouse it is a bad habbit in the PHP community (arrays are for storing data which are same types).

### Hashing

First see @Peter Taylor's comment. In my example i'm injecting an IHasher implementation through the constructor but this is not the best i think. You should have some membership provider stuff and that can have a configurable hashing method what can be used at authentication/user registration and password changing scenarios.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for posting. The reason I want to use an error class, is because I want to manage all errors in all my classes the same way. I'm trying to get practice using other objects inside objects. As far as the PDO usage, could you provide an example of that wrapper? I agree with fetching objects instead of assoc arrays, I overlooked that. Thank you! As far as hashing, I will look into the salt. I've heard of it, just have never used it yet. Thxs!

Comment: See Database class here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100427/static-method-calling-result-of-mysql-query/13100788#13100788
This is a very basic class, the next could be a new Exucute and Query method, for example: public function Query($queryString, array $params) { /* ... */ } here you can not use names parameters int the query instead those you have to use question marks.

Comment: Hey Peter, I took a look! Thanks!! I have come to the conclusion that in order for me to learn the right way to program, I need to find an open source application that is VERY SMALL, probably less than 20 classes. But large enough to see how it is developed and how the individual classes interact. Do you happen to know of such a project? I only want to study the absolute best principles. I absolutely hate to ask, but do you think you could write the entire Login class the way that you would write it and post it?

Comment: That way I can learn from it. Most likely it will be the accepted answer because it will be most beneficial to many people who are trying to learn proper class design. The sad thing is that when people post questions on here, they truely are looking to learn ALOT, but sometimes answers get posted that just teach a little. Like for instance, the post that has the highest score. It simply talks about adding a SALT instead of a sha1 hash. Ok that's great, but it doesn't teach any true class design. You see what I mean?

Comment: When I say "the exact way you would do it" I am referring to the "wrapper" and the whole nine yards. A true class design for all to feast off of who really want to learn.

Comment: Neither of these are unique to your answer, but: Throwing an exception is not the correct course of action for a failed authentication.  An exception implies that something particularly out of the ordinary happened.  A failed authentication is just as expected as a successful authentication (depending on perspective).  Also, authentication and identity persistence should not be tied together.  What if the consumer of this class wanted to check a username/password combination *without* then logging in as that user?  That's two separate concerns.

Comment: @darga33 to write a complete solution is difficult becouse it requires a huge infrastructure: how do you process the request, how can you inject configurations etc. The solution will contain a lot classes: Membership (this can be full static depending on your solution), MembershipUser, IMembershipProvider interface for real backends (SQL, XML, memory), IPasswordService for the providers to do the hashing, some kind of session handling stuff with authentication and session validation. The best thing to do is try put these things together (without any implementation just skeletons) and ask.

Comment: Yeah Peter, I know what you mean. It can be very very complex. I'm not actually looking for a complex complete solution. I'm looking for a barebones solution but that utilizes some kind of error handling technique that allows for errors to be displayed back to the user. It's something that I think I'm going to have to spend some time on to wrap my mind around. Thanks so much for all the help! It was much appreciated! Everyones answers were great!